# Definition of cyclic permutation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have it defined that a formal definition of a cyclic permutation is:

$$(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)(r) =  \begin{cases} a_{i+1}& \text{if $r = a_i$, $i<m$}, \\
 a_1 &\text{if $r = a_m$}, \\ r &\text{if $r\notin \{a_1,a_2,...,a_m\}$}.\end{cases}$$

I'm confused about this notation, afaik $$(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$$ describes a cyclic permutation, but what does $$(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)(r)$$ mean? i.e. what is $(r)$?

Comment: A permutation is a function which maps the element $r$ to another point in the underlying set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget that a permuation is a bijection $\sigma: S_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}\to S_n$ then we can write $\sigma(r)$ where $r\in S_n$ and in your example $\sigma$ is the cyclic permutation.