# Power of an element of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

I am wondering why the terminology for cyclic groups is not used for permutations.

If we have a permutation $\sigma$ on a set $A$, then for any element $a$ of $A$ we can define the integer power $a^n$ recursively in the following way:

- $a^0 = a$,
- $a^{n+1} = \sigma(a^n)$,
- $a^{n-1} = \sigma^{-1}(a^n)$,

where $\sigma(x)$ is the image element of $x$, and $\sigma^{-1}(x)$ is the element which image is $x$.

Thus, every element $a$ of $A$ generates the subset of powers of $a$ (let's denote it $[a]$).

We can say that $[a]$ is a "subpermutation" of $\sigma$ meaning $\sigma$ defines a bijection on $[a]$.

Clearly, "subpermutation" means there is a decomposition of $\sigma$ onto two *disjoint* permutations:

- $\sigma = \sigma([a])\ \circ\ \sigma(\overline{[a]})$,

where $\sigma([a])$ is a permutation of $[a]$, and $\sigma(\overline{[a]})$ is a *disjoint* permutation of the *complementary* subset ([disjoint permutations commutes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2704904/427611)).

The "subpermutation" $[a]$ has exactly the same relation to $\sigma$ as cyclic subgroup to group, so we can apply all the definitions and statements for cyclic (sub)groups to permutations.

In particular, we must agree that a cyclic permutation can be *finite* or *infinite*.

However, all the sources I've seen insist that a cyclic permutation is *finite*:

[Definition of cyclic permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/616586/427611)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPermutation.html

Is there a flaw in the definition of the integer power of an element of a permutation?

Comment: What do you want to do with such things?  For one, they don't necessarily form a subgroup.

Comment: @Randall They do form a disjoint permutation, don't they?

Comment: No.  Consider the identity permutation as $\sigma$ with $a=1$.  Then your set is $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots\}$.

Comment: @Randall No. Applying the same logic as for cyclic subgroups the set is $\{1\}$.

Comment: I thought you were describing a sequence of powers, so I wrote it as as sequence.  Either way, what you get is not a group, so you cannot "apply all other definitions of cyclic groups" to it.

Comment: This kind of thing is sometimes called an "orbit."

Comment: @Randall If we replace "subgroup" with "disjoint permutation" shouldn't we get exactly the same statements as for groups and cyclic subgroups?

Comment: What is a "disjoint permutation"?

Comment: @Randall https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2704904/427611

Comment: You need TWO permutations to speak of them being disjoint.  This makes no sense in the context of your question.  I'd edit it.

Comment: @Randall I've edited the question. Is it better now?